# Google Sign-In permission list changes between authorizatons

Tags: ios, google-signin

I've noticed that if I’ve already authorized my app and then ask for authorization again, the listed permissions change.

The first time the permission list is:

- View your email address
- View your basic profile info

The second time the permission list is:

- Have offline access

To be clear I am not changing `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].scopes` the `NSArray` is empty both times.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offline access permission notification is presented every time that access is granted (e.g. a refresh token is handed to an app) but does not get shown when other permissions are present. If you disconnect ([revoke the app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/disconnect)) and connect again, all of the permissions will be shown.